# JSON.stringify is not working in blackberry mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

JSON.stringify is not working in blackberry mobile  it is working great in iphone and other browser. it is not prompting it in below example in blackberry mobile:

```
  function sup() {
        this.name;
    }

    var SUP = new sup();

        SUP.name = 'XYZ' ;
        var tt = JSON.stringify(SUP);
        alert(tt);
```

Comment: Normally, questions on Stack Overflow should be *questions* ([more](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)). I've guessed that your question is: What should I do about the Blackberry browser not supporting the `JSON` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a fallback mechanism so browser uses the native JSON support if present, otherwise it download the library that @T.J. Crowder pointed out

Something like this should do the trick

```
<script>window.JSON|| 
    document.write("<script src='js/my-json-library.js'>\x3C/script>")
</script>
```

Comment: where can i download this my-json-library.js??

Comment: do i need to add all javascript files or only named JSON.js? because it is giving error at line return JSON.parse(this, filter);

Comment: @samirprogrammer: it seems that with json2.js you're done for a starting

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that version of the Blackberry browser doesn't support the new `JSON` object, which was introduced in [ES5](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1) (so, just recently). You can find several polyfills/shims, including [ones from the "introducer" of JSON himself](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/).

Comment: Thanks Crowder.. Actually i want to pass this object to Ajax Call... is there any other way i can pass many objects in one to ajax call..your help higly appreciated!!!

Comment: @samirprogrammer: I'd probably stick with JSON. JSON's not a bad way of sending a complex object graph to the server. Note that `json2.js` from the link above minifies to ~3,400 bytes, most of which is specifically for `JSON.stringify`, so adding it to your existing script won't make an appreciable difference.